# Create/Store Thumbnail when picture is taken or live render when list is loaded?

Tags: android, performance, listview, thumbnails

I am developing an Android app using Android Studio.  The app will have the user take photographs and then display those photos as low-resolution thumbnails in a listview along with some other information.  I am using a sqlite database with a field for the file name of the image to be called whenever the listview is loaded.  There will potentially be several hundred pictures stored on the SD card.  Each time a listview is loaded, there may be 50 or more thumbnails displayed.

The debate is whether to render the lo-res thumbnail from the original file each and every time the listview is generated and destroy it afterwards verses whether to create a permanent thumbnail version of the image at the time the picture is taken and call the thumbnail in an effort to save the rendering time. Will there be a noticeable difference in performance (how quickly the listview loads) in one method over the other?

Since I'm storing all the images on an SD card, storage space is not really an issue.

Also, the app will only ever work on the particular device its installed on.  It won't be sending information to other devices.  The thumbnail that would be generated would be optimized for the particular device's screen at the time it's created.

Answer (score 0):

In this case caching makes sense; it's not only about performance, but also about CPU time, which effectively means the battery. You *might* still need to provide a fallback to live-scaling, in case the user refuses to grant access to external storage (where the original images are located matters).

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I hadn't even considered the impact to the battery.

Comment: @Matthew as a rule of thumb... the less processing, the more battery time.